# How do I use .html.erb as a file extension for my views with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

If I have the following Sinatra code:

```
get '/hi' do
  erb :hello
end
```

This works great if I have a file called `views/hello.erb`.  However if I have a file called `views/hello.html.erb` Sinatra can't find the file and gives me an error.  How do I tell Sinatra I want it to look for `.html.erb` as a valid .erb extension?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sinatra uses [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/) to render its templates, and to associate extensions with them. All you have to do is tell Tilt it should use ERB to render that extension:

```
Tilt.register Tilt::ERBTemplate, 'html.erb'

get '/hi' do
  erb :hello
end
```

**Edit** to answer follow-up question. There's no `#unregister` and also note that Sinatra will prefer hello.erb over hello.html.erb. The way around the preference issue is to either override the `erb` method or make your own render method:

```
Tilt.register Tilt::ERBTemplate, 'html.erb'

def herb(template, options={}, locals={})
  render "html.erb", template, options, locals
end

get '/hi' do
  herb :hello
end
```

That will prefer hello.html.erb, but will still fall back on hello.erb if it can't find hello.html.erb. If you *really* want to prevent .erb files from being found under any circumstances, you could, I guess, subclass ERBTemplate and register that against .html.erb instead, but frankly that just doesn't sound worth it.

Comment: Thank you!  Works great, and also leaves `.erb` working too.  Not that I'd want to mix conventions, but still handy to know.  Do you know - if I didn't want to handle .erb any longer and just .html.erb, could I call something other than `.register` to disable .erb extensions?

Answer (score 9):

This should do

```
get '/hi' do
  erb :'hello.html'
end
```

Or alternatively

```
get '/hi' do
  erb 'hello.html'.to_sym
end
```

Comment: +1.  A reasonable alternative to Issac's answer, thank you.  I want to set this convention globally rather than do this for every single route so I went with his answer.

Comment: That is a not a good suggestion given there is no ERB extension