# render html.erb template in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can render an `html.erb` template in sintara?

For example, this works fine for a file named `payment.erb`:

```
<%= render erb :payment %>
```

The file I'm trying to use is named `payment.html.erb`, so what is the syntax for that `render` line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741585/how-do-i-use-html-erb-as-a-file-extension-for-my-views-with-sinatra

Comment: see here https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap/search?l=html%2Berb

Comment: ohhh.. it is soo simple.. thanks @koffeinfrei